# How can I extract the data behind a modelling plot in Python?

Tags: python, plot, model

I have been using the lightweight_mmm package and other packages to fit some models and then plot them with matplotlib.

An example code I have used for a plot is:

```
plot_out_of_sample_model = plot.plot_out_of_sample_model_fit(out_of_sample_predictions=new_predictions,
                                 out_of_sample_target=target_scaler.transform(target[split_point:]))
```

I have other plots too that I am trying to extract data from, such as:

```
plot.plot_media_baseline_contribution_area_plot(media_mix_model=mmm,
                                                target_scaler=target_scaler,
                                                channel_names = data,
                                                fig_size=(20,10)
                                                )
```

```
plot.plot_bars_media_metrics(metric=roi_hat, metric_name="ROI hat", channel_names=data)
```

Could somebody please help me work out how to get the specific data points that generate the output please? Basically I want to re-create the plot myself, but make some formatting changes.

I have tried to use lines such as:

```
import matplotlib
import _tkinter
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
plot_out_of_sample_model.show()


ax = plt.gca() # to get the axis
ax.get_lines()

ax.get_children()



import pickle

ax=plot.plot_out_of_sample_model_fit(out_of_sample_predictions=new_predictions,
                                 out_of_sample_target=target_scaler.transform(target[split_point:]))

pickle.dump(ax, open("plot.pickle","wb"))
plt.show()
```